# My app is not in near me tab app store

Tags: ios, app-store

I submitted an application to the app store, but the app store doesn't show my app on the "near me" tab in the app store application.
I want to release an update for my app and this time I would like to app store show my app in near me
how is it possible?

Comment: You can't directly control the "Popular apps near me" section. That's a list of popular apps near you. If your app is not a popular app near your current location, it won't show up there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the title of the screen for the "near me" tab, it is actually "Popular Near Me". This screen contains apps that a lot of people near your current location have downloaded. There is no direct link between an app and a location. For example when I check the "Near Me" tab I see the local newspaper and public transport apps but also a national banking app and the podcast app.

If you can get a lot of people near you to download your app then it will be on that list.

Comment: so this is it.if my app became popular on a specific location then it will be on "Near Me" tab.thanks